# Salesforce DX Running bunch of command using script in one shot

Tags: salesforcedx

I am trying to automate the test data migration in all my sandbox, I tried doing the data migration in more then 5 objects in one sandbox and that worked perfectly.
But now, I want to automate this process, so that I don't have to load the data by hitting all the commands, so I am looking for some scripting kind of process, using which all my commands will run as they are in the script I just have to run the script once and the data will load in all the object in one sandbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Using Salesforce DX, you can simply write a script for your OS.

In Windows and Linux, you just write the code you want in a plain text file:

```
sfdx force:data:import ...
sfdx force:data:import ...
sfdx force:data:import ...
```

In Windows, save the file ending in ".bat". In your command prompt, you can then run your script:

```
C:\Users\myname\workspace\project> setup-test-data.bat
```

In Linux, you set the executable bit on the file, then you run it like a script:

```
~/workspace/project $ chmod +x setup-test-data
~/workspace/project $ . setup-test-data
```

Comment: I just did this on my Windows PC saving it as but file and it executes only the first line of the script

Answer (score 2):

It is not very clear what your current process is which you are trying to replicate with SFDX, so I am going to make some assumptions.

It sounds like you have 5 existing scripts that you run after a Sandbox refresh, that populate various SObject data in said Sandbox.  With SFDX you can use the `data:tree` framework to run commands against the [SObject Tree API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm) to pull data from an existing org and import it into a Sandbox or ScratchOrg:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm#cli_reference_tree_import